# Client session storage in an akka-http server

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

In an akka-http service, how does one cache some information, per client session? This is not quite obvious in the docs. I would for example like to create an actor for each connection.

Where should I create the actor, and how do I get reference to it from inside my stages?

My service is bound something like this:

```
  val serverSource: Source[Http.IncomingConnection, Future[Http.ServerBinding]] =
    Http().bind(interface = bindAddress, port = bindPort)

  val bindingFuture: Future[Http.ServerBinding] =
    serverSource
      .to(Sink.foreach { connection => 
        connection.handleWithSyncHandler (requestHandler)
        // seems like I should set up some session state storage here,
        // such as my actor      
      })
      .run()
```

...

and later on:

```
  val packetProcessor: Flow[A, B, Unit] =  Flow[A]
    .map {
      case Something =>
        // can i use the actor here, or access my session state?
    }
```

I suspect I'm probably misinterpreting the whole paradigm in trying to make this fit. I can't tell if there is anything built in or how much I need to implement manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [`Agent`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/agents.html) to be a very convenient mechanism for concurrent caching.

Say, for example, you want to keep a running `Set` of all the remote addresses that you have been connected to.  You can setup an Agent to store the values and a `Flow` to write to the cache:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import akka.agent.Agent

import scala.collection.immutable

val addressCache = Agent(immutable.Set.empty[java.net.InetSocketAddress])

import akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow

val cacheAddressFlow = Flow[IncomingConnection] map { conn =>
  addressCache send (_ + conn.remoteAddress) //updates the cache
  conn //forwards the connection to the rest of the stream
}
```

This Flow can then be made part of your Stream:

```
val bindingFuture: Future[Http.ServerBinding] =
  serverSource.via(cacheAddressFlow)
              .to(Sink.foreach { connection => 
    connection.handleWithSyncHandler (requestHandler)
  })
  .run()
```

You can then "query" the cache completely outside of the binding logic:

```
def somewhereElseInTheCode = {
  val currentAddressSet = addressCache.get

  println(s"address count so far: ${currentAddressSet.size}")
}
```

If your goal is to send all `IncomingConnection` values to an `Actor` for processing then this can be accomplished with [`Sink.actorRef`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.3/?_ga=1.155440379.1917589872.1429296441#akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink$):

```
object ConnectionStreamTerminated

class ConnectionActor extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case conn : IncomingConnection => ???
    case ConnectionStreamTerminated => ???
  }
}

val actorRef = actorSystem actorOf Props[ConnectionActor]

val actorSink = 
  Sink.actorRef[IncomingConnection](actorRef, ConnectionStreamTerminated)

val bindingFuture: Future[Http.ServerBinding] =
  serverSource.runWith(actorSink)
```

Comment: So basically, roll my own service-wide cache? This seems like something basic missing from Akka-HTTP. I was hoping I can get to some actor identifying the connection and start from there.  I may have to go with the approach you propose, but there is probably a lot more code for cache management now. :(  Thanks!

Comment: @WillIAm I appended to my answer with a suggestion that seems like it is more inline with what you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks, it does seem almost like I want indeed. What I'm trying to figure out though is, isn't this sending all streams to one ActorRef? That could potentially blow up the Actor's cache or at least slow down all streams. Maybe I'm missing the gist of my original question -- how to create the ConnectionActor per connection (or do I need to go back to rolling up a cache?).

Comment: @WillIAm You are welcome.  Yes, this is sending all IncomingConnection to the same Actor.  But typically this is ok because you usually do something like `conn.handleWith(...)` which materializes into a seperate stream.  Therefore your Actor doesn't really do much work except materialize other Actors.  Remember, there are two levels streams: (1) a source of Connections, (2) a Source of `HttpRequest` for each connection...

Answer (score 1):

For the reason that the suggested Agents have been deprecated. I would suggests to use  [`akka-http-session`](http://github.com/softwaremill/akka-http-session). It makes sure session data is secure and cannot be tampered with.